# Can I change order on dynamicdata

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, dynamic-data, asp.net-dynamic-data

In dynamic-data it is possible to change the order of items ? 
I have a list of topic and I want to modify (with coherance verification) the OrderId attribute, do you have a simple way to do it ?

Comment: Do you mean order of rows or order of columns? it is possible in both cases of course. Rows is slightly more complicated but not that much.

Comment: Hey @ChrisCannon I mean order of rows

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the DisplayColumnAttribute in DataAnnotations allows for a default sort column.

public DisplayColumnAttribute(string displayColumn, **string sortColumn, bool sortDescending**);